# Kmeans clustering and Text mining in R

Tags: r, k-means, text-mining

I have a txt file which contains twitter data(only 1 file). I loaded it into R using streamR and the parseTweets function.  I am required to do Kmeans clustering on this data.  First, I need to clean and prepare the data, but the data is a mix of numbers, characters it is not allowing me to do: (for example) content transformation tolower.
How can I get rid of all unwanted characters from this data? I need only the plain text. No numbers, special characters etc

```
*library(streamR)
install.packages("RCurl")
install.packages("bitops")
install.packages("rjson")
library(bitops)
library(RCurl)
library(rjson)
library(NLP)
library(tm)
library(SnowballC)
library(XML)
tweets.df<-parseTweets('tweetsStream.txt', simplify = FALSE);
tweets.df<-tm_map(tweets.df,content_transformer(tolower));
Error in UseMethod("tm_map", x) : 
  no applicable method for 'tm_map' applied to an object of class "data.frame"*
```

Answer (score 1):

The tm_map function resquires a Corpus as input datatype. Try this:

```
docs <- Corpus(DirSource(cname))
docs <- tm_map(docs, tolower)
```

Find the full example here: https://rstudio-pubs-static.s3.amazonaws.com/31867_8236987cf0a8444e962ccd2aec46d9c3.html

For further details you can always run

`??tm_map` or `??tm` to get to the whole documentation in your R console.

Regards,
Markus